# can I get the object file id for a deleted file with git?

Tags: bash, git

If i run:

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete
```

I can get a list of all the deleted files in a repo, but it doesn't actually give me the object id for those files.

I want to be able to run git cat-file on the actual deleted file object in .git/object/
Is there a way to get a list of object ids for deleted files so I can git cat-file them?

I don't want to have to actually restore the file to view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the `sha1` of the commit where the file was deleted, you can find the file's content in the *parent* of this commit.

```
# if 'sha1' points at the commit, 'sha1~' will point at its parent
git show sha1~
```

You don't really need the hash of the file, `git show` or `git cat-file` both understand how to navigate in a commit's content by path :

```
# to view the content of the file :
git show sha1~:path/to/dir/file
git cat-file -p sha1~:path/to/dir/file

# if you want to see the hash of the file :
git ls-tree sha1~:path/to/dir
git cat-file -p sha1~:path/to/dir
```

---

[edit]

From your comment : it looks like the `sha1` you found is not the commit which deleted the file you were inspecting.

To confirm this, run :

```
git show --name-status sha1
```

If your intention is to find the commit that deleted file `path/to/file`, I would suggest using the following `git log` command :

```
git log --name-status -- path/to/file
# you should quickly spot the commits which display :
D    path/to/file
```

`--graph` is often very useful to make sense of the history,
`--oneline` gives a view similar to what graphical viewers do.
You can try both of the following to see for yourself :

```
git log --graph --name-status -- path/to/file
git log --graph --oneline --name-status -- path/to/file
```

Comment: it looks like the files content is also in the commit where the file was deleted. I can see the files content in both sha1 and sha1~

Comment: glad I could help. I added some extra notes in my answer.